# Error fatal en un include PHP

Tags: php

En php tengo esta 'arquitectura' de carpetas:`(lo que esta en negritas son las carpetas y lo que no los archivos).`

**NOTA:** La carpeta compartido **NO** esta dentro de la Curriculum.

**Estudiantes**

- **Curriculum**
- informacion_estudiantes.php
- **Compartido**
- navs.php

En el archivo `informacion_estudiantes.php` todo esta en `html` pero con extension `php` por el cual si voy hacer un `include` debo hacer esto `<?php include... ?>`

**EL PROBLEMA:**

me arroja un warning `"Failed opening '../Compartido/navs.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')"` cuando intento hacer el include al  archivo navs.php desde mi archivo informacion_estudiantes.php...este es lo que yo hago `<?php include("../Compartido/navs.php") ?>`...espero haberme hecho entender y cual seria la manera correcta..he intentado de varias formas y no me funciona.

Comment: Y exactamente como pones la función  en el include? sí no pones el código difícilmente se te puede ayudar

Comment: que pena, este sistema de stacoverflow es tan avanzado que si pongo una etiqueta que comienza en php no lo lee toca ponerlo con comillas personalizadas...ya edite la publicacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si aun no solucionas el problema, prueba lo siguiente

```
require_once(APPPATH.'Estudiantes/Compartido/navs.php');
```

para regresar a tu directorio padre **Estudiantes** y posteriormente accedas a la carpeta donde se encuentra tu script

Espero te sirva amigo..

saludos

Answer (score 3):

Debes de ponerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
include('./Compartido/navs.php') ?>
```

Te sobra un `.` ya que con `..` estás haciendo referencia a la carpeta padre.

Comment: include(./Compartido/navs.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Prueba poniendo tu `informacion_estudiantes.php` en la carpeta donde se encuentra tus carpetas Curriculum y Compartido

Comment: si lo hago de la manera que tu dices me funciona pero no requiero de esa manera ya que necesito tener un orden

Comment: ¿Has probado cambiando las `"` por `'` ?

Comment: si, ya lo intente de esa manera y no da

Answer (score 1):

Si lo de cnbandicoot no te funcionó podrías intentar creando una url absoulta

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
include($path."/Compartido/navs.php") ?>
```

Comment: pero esa url absulota no altera la seguridad de acceso a subcarpetas?

Comment: A que te refieres con alterar la seguridad de acceso a subcarpetas?

Comment: bueno no tan claro es porque quedo mal publicado...es decri....CARPETA1/CARPETA3/CARPETA10/INDEX.PHP , Si tu vas quitanto poco a poco la direccion url te va mostrando el contenido de cada carpeta a eso es que me refiero

Comment: Ya lo veo, de cualquier forma, te va a mostrar lo mismo con una url relativa, siempre te va a mostar el htpp://localhost/tuProyecto/Compartido
en la url, ya que la forma en que lo pongas llegará a esa url, para mejorar la seguridad tendrías que manejar ruteos y permisos, para eso un framework te facilita enormemente la cosa

Comment: estoy haciendo uso de codeigniter pero igual esa forma de poner la url absoluta no me da muy buena espina de ser asi como tu dices lo mejor seria usar un controlador pero ya llevaría un poco de mas de trabajo igualmente gracias por tu colaboracion.

Comment: Si estas usando codeigniter deberías usar su MVC, si no lo estás usando realmente no sé para que usas el framework. Si lo usas es fácil cargando el helper url en el controlador $this->load->helper('url');
Una vez hecho esto este helper puedes usar redirect('/othercontroller/action'), o incluso tiene base_url() que es para lo mismo que el path. Las URL absolutas no son malas

Comment: se supone que la metodología de este framework es trabajar con la arquitectura MVC asi es como trabajo,crei conveniente y de mayor facil hacer un include para un archivo insignificativo, pero bueno si tu dices que trabajar con una url absoluta no es malo ps lo intentare con el base_url(); gracias.