# ¿Cómo leer mi conexión php que está en otra carpeta?

Tags: php

Me muestra un error de que no encuentra el archivo, le seré sincero, apenas estoy conociendo php, y la verdad no sé cómo entrar a la carpeta que tiene mi conexión a la base de datos. Adjunto el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura de las carpetas es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es entrar a la carpeta connections, que dentro tiene el archivo conexion.php. Pero me marca el error antes mencionado.
En mi archivo de registrarArticulos.php la primera línea lo tengo de esta manera:

```
<?php
require_once 'connections/conexion.php'; /*es aquí donde me está marcando el error, no puede entrar a la carpeta connections*/
?>
```

Comment: Si está en la misma carpeta su archivo la carpeta de conexión, como lo tiene estaría bien, pero al parecer está en una carpeta anterior, por lo tanto tendría que devolverse una carpeta con `../`  , sería `require_once '../connections/conexion.php';` o las carpetas que se tenga que devolver(2 carpetas se devuelve) `require_once '../../connections/conexion.php';`

Comment: Voy a probar su código

Comment: Me muestran estos errores: Warning: require_once(../connections/conexion.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mautomotriz/public_html/admin/funciones/articulo/registrarArticulo.php on line 2

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../connections/conexion.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mautomotriz/public_html/admin/funciones/articulo/registrarArticulo.php on line 2

Comment: su archivo `registrarArticulo.php` debe llamar a la el archivo `connections/conexion.php` trazando la ruta hacia este, entonces `../` es para salir de la carpeta una vez, con `../../` se devuelve dos carpetas y así sucesivamente, lo que debe verificar es que esté trazando bien la ruta.

Comment: Según la estructura que muestras, tu carpeta `connections` se encuentra dos directorios hacia atrás de donde se encuentra el script en el cual quieres usar uno de sus archivos, por lo tanto, debes ponerlo así: **`require_once ('../../connections/conexion.php');`** nótese que la ruta y el nombre del archivo debe ir entre comillas simples `'` o bien entre comillas dobles `"`.

Comment: Si buscas el mensaje de error en el sitio, verás que hay muchas preguntas (con respuesta) sobre este mismo problema; algunas son específicas a algún plugin/framework, pero otras no y te podrían servir de guía y ayuda (el código es diferente pero la causa es la misma). Por ejemplo, es el caso de [Error con las rutas de los fichero en PHP al hacer require()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/52643/250), o de [Error fatal en un include PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/46337/250) (entre otras). Lee [ask] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Claramente tienes un problema con las rutas, si no tienes muy claro el directorio actual en el que se esta ejecutando el script lo mejor es que te apoyes en `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` para partir desde la raíz.

Por ejemplo:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/connections/conexion.php');
```

> **'DOCUMENT_ROOT'**
>
> El directorio raíz de documentos del servidor en el cual se está ejecutando el script actual, según está definida en el archivo de configuración del servidor.

Documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php